# Regex that matches [digits space operator digits] [digits operator digits] but not [digits space digits]

Tags: regex

I have written a regex for matching part of the python syntax.

```
"^(\s*(\d*\s*(\+*|-*|\*{0,2}|\/{0,2}|%{0,1})\s*\d+))*$"
```

It currently matches:

23 + 23

23+23

23 23

I am trying to get "23 23" to not match but still match the others. Any possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
\d+\s*(?:[-+%]|\*\*?|//?)\s*\d+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/2QpmL0/4

Comment: Glad to be of help. Not too sure what you mean by matching the `-` and the `+` between 0 and infinite times. Can you update your question with examples of such scenarios?

Comment: Thank you so much! The whole thing ended up being: 
"^(\s*(\d*\s*(?:[-+]+|\%|\*\*?|//?)\s*\d+))*$"

It's working all well now!